# How to create Fancy Title Headers

Tags: formatting, titles, fancyhdr

I want to create a Fancy Title Header for an Article, like the one shown below:

[image]

Can someone please provide some hint on how to achieve this?

Comment: Do you mean a header (as in header/footer) or are you referring to the title of a sectional unit, like `\section`?

Comment: I was looking for a title of a sectional unit. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a solution using [`titleps`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titleps):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titleps}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand\HeaderTitle{Time For Action -- Embedding a picture within text}
\newpagestyle{myheader}
{
\sethead{}{\colorbox{black}{\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep\relax}{%
  \strut\textcolor{white}{\sffamily\large\bfseries\HeaderTitle}}}}{}
}
\pagestyle{myheader}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

The idea is to use a new page style using a `\parbox` of width equal to `\textwidth` inside a `\colorbox`.

Here's the same idea but using now [`fancyhdr`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand\HeaderTitle{Time For Action -- Embedding a picture within text}

\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhf[C]{\colorbox{black}{\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep\relax}{%
  \strut\textcolor{white}{\sffamily\large\bfseries\HeaderTitle}}}}
\setlength\headheight{18pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-3]

\end{document}
```

Now that I reread the question, I am not sure if a header (as in header/footer) was required or if the question is about the tiles for a sectional unit (`\section`, for example). My two examples above solve the first case; for the second case, here's a solution with [`titlesec`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) (in both cases the idea for the solution reamains the same):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\large\sffamily\bfseries}{}{0em}
  {\colorbox{black}{\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep\relax}{%
    \textcolor{white}{\thesection\quad#1}}}}
\titleformat{name=\section,numberless}
  {\normalfont\large\sffamily\bfseries}{}{0em}
  {\colorbox{black}  {\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep\relax}{%
    \textcolor{white}{#1}}}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]
\section*{Time For Action -- Embedding a picture within text}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]