# Problem with importing logo in footer

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, includegraphics

I wanted to use this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/578213/188245) to insert my own logo instead of the bluish grid example logo here using the following codes unsuccessfully:

```latex
% Assemply of the footer four boxes to \Fframex
\JoinCoffins*\Fframex[l,t]\Hthinrulex[l,t](-5mm,3mm)    % horizontal line (X, Y) offsets
\JoinCoffins\Fframex[l,t]\Fleftx[l,t](-5mm,0mm)
\JoinCoffins\Fframex[hc,t]\Fcenterx[l,t](-10mm,0mm)
%\JoinCoffins\Fframex[r,t]\Flogox[r,t](5mm,0mm) % logo bluish grid
\includegraphics[width=3cm,height=3cm]{Resources/Mushroom1.png} % <---insert my own logo
```

How can I insert the logo from the path correctly by modifying this snippet?

Comment: Please always provide a full but minimal example that others can copy and test as is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to change a different snippet:

```
% Filling the footer boxes  
\SetHorizontalCoffin\Flogox{% a figure, logo , etc
    \includegraphics[height=70pt,width=70pt]{example-grid-100x100pt}  
}
```

Change the `example-grid-100x100pt` to `Resources/Mushroom1.png` (you probably don't have to specify `.png`) and leave the `\JoinCoffins\Fframex[r,t]\Flogox[r,t](5mm,0mm)` unchanged.